# How to enable html file button in type script - Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am new to Angular.

I have a following button control in html file and i am trying to enable it in the ts (type script) file on map click event.

```
       <div *ngIf="editVisible" class="p-col-1">
      <button label="Update" icon="far fa-save" class="p-button-raised p-button-primary" pButton
        [disabled]="!has(Permission.Admin_Pod_Location_Full_Control) || cleanData"
        (click)="updateLocation()"></button>
      </div>
```

I have tried this in the Type Script file button it doesn't enable the button.

```
   MapClick(event) {
        const button = document.getElementsByClassName('p-button-raised p-button-primary');
        button.setAttribute('disabled', '');
   }
```

Comment: `const button = document.querySelector('.p-button-raised.p-button-primary');`

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` method returns an array-like collection of elements, not a single element.

you need to access the specific button you want to disable using an index.

Try this:

```
MapClick(event) {
    const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('p-button-raised p-button-primary');
    
    // Assuming you want to disable the first button in the collection
    if (buttons.length > 0) {
        buttons[0].setAttribute('disabled', '');
    }
}
```

(Assuming that you want to disable the first button in the collection.)

Comment: Only one button has that class 'p-button-raised p-button-primary'